# Error running dotnet core 3.0 docker image on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core

### Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Create a webapi project template using the dotnet CLI (dotnet --version = 3.0.100)
2. Build the dockerfile to create image (see dockerfile below)
3. Run the docker image on local docker (works fine)
4. Push this docker image to a docker registry
5. Deploy this onto K8s (were using EKS on AWS)

### Expected behavior

Pod starts up, and runs the webapi

### Actual behavior

Pod fails to start up, with the following error in logs:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<util::AprException>'
  what():  BaseException: Could not find the requested symbol. at /opt/jenkins/oa-s173/cmake-64-d/agent/native/shared/libutil/src/main/cpp/util/AprException.h:54 at static void util::AprException::check(apr_status_t)
  at liboneagentdotnet.so [0x90ec22]
  at liboneagentdotnet.so [0x90ed1b]
  at liboneagentdotnet.so [0x90ed7c]
  at liboneagentdotnet.so [0x143d61]
  at liboneagentdotnet.so [0x144adb]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024acee2]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024accef]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024a4e48]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024acb40]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024aca6c]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024ac77a]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024a3299]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024a2dd1]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024a2d4e]
  at unknown [0x7f4a024a2425]
  at unknown [0x7f4a020ac426]
  at unknown [0x7f4a020aca3d]
  at libcoreclr.so(CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x7b) [0x24dcae]
  at libcoreclr.so(CallDescrWorkerWithHandler(CallDescrData*, int)+0x74) [0x17dfc4]
  at libcoreclr.so(DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper(CallDescrData*, ContextTransitionFrame*, int)+0x86) [0x17e0b6]
  at libcoreclr.so(DispatchCallSimple(unsigned long*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int)+0xb6) [0x17e236]
  at libcoreclr.so(MethodTable::RunClassInitEx(Object**)+0x1a1) [0x115d61]
  at libcoreclr.so(MethodTable::DoRunClassInitThrowing()+0x2f8) [0x1162e8]
  at libcoreclr.so(JIT_GetSharedNonGCStaticBase_Helper+0xcf) [0x1b916f]
  at unknown [0x7f4a020ac2ea]
  at unknown [0x7f4a020ab4ec]
  at unknown [0x7f4a020aadad]
  at libcoreclr.so(CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x7b) [0x24dcae]
  at libcoreclr.so(CallDescrWorkerWithHandler(CallDescrData*, int)+0x74) [0x17dfc4]
  at libcoreclr.so(DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper(CallDescrData*, ContextTransitionFrame*, int)+0x86) [0x17e0b6]
  at libcoreclr.so(DispatchCallSimple(unsigned long*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int)+0xb6) [0x17e236]
  at libcoreclr.so(MethodTable::RunClassInitEx(Object**)+0x1a1) [0x115d61]
  at libcoreclr.so(MethodTable::DoRunClassInitThrowing()+0x2f8) [0x1162e8]
  at libcoreclr.so [0x29c00b]
  at libcoreclr.so [0x2551cc]
  at libcoreclr.so [0x2548c4]
  at libcoreclr.so [0x2546b3]
  at libcoreclr.so [0x29ba01]
  at libcoreclr.so(MethodTable::EnsureInstanceActive()+0x92) [0x115a92]
  at libcoreclr.so(MethodDesc::EnsureActive()+0x22) [0x109ae2]
  at libcoreclr.so [0x262507]
  at libcoreclr.so [0x26291f]
  at libcoreclr.so(CorHost2::ExecuteAssembly(unsigned int, char16_t const*, int, char16_t const**, unsigned int*)+0x240) [0xcae90]
  at libcoreclr.so(coreclr_execute_assembly+0xd3) [0xa3c63]
  at libhostpolicy.so [0x161c2]
  at libhostpolicy.so(corehost_main+0xcb) [0x16a1b]
  at libhostfxr.so [0x2ab0f]
  at libhostfxr.so [0x296a2]
  at libhostfxr.so(hostfxr_main_startupinfo+0x92) [0x246f2]
  at dotnet [0xc440]
  at dotnet [0xc9fd]
  at libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea) [0x2409a]
  at dotnet(_start+0x28) [0x2f3f]
```

### Additional information

dockerfile is below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /build

COPY /src .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o ./out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /build/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Weather.dll"]
```

It is unusual that this is happening only on K8s, were testing this as part of a migration to dotnetcore 3.0

This behavior does not change when specifying the `runtime` flag when executing `dotnet publish`.

### Output of `docker version`

```
Local docker for windows version: Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
Container Runtime Version (on K8s):  docker://18.6.1
```

### General Comments

Not totally sure what the issue is here, I would be happy with a mere understanding of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by Dynatrace not supporting the version of dotnet core we were targeting. Disabling this resolved the issue.